# Og meta tags don't generate with nuxt content

Tags: nuxt.js, meta-tags, nuxtjs3, nuxt-content

I am using NuxtContent with Nuxt3. I have a document that uses the following tags:

```
---
title: "test"
description: "test"
image:
  src: '/test.webp'
  alt: 'test'
head:
  meta:
    - name: 'keywords'
      content: 'test'
---
```

This results in proper title, description and keyword tags in my `<head />`, but it doesn't generate `og:image` or any other `og` tags. Here is a link to the documentation:
https://content.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-content-head#parameters

Is my implementation wrong?

Comment: I can't even get my title and description tags to appear right. Do you have anything in your nuxt.config.js file? I can't seem to figure out what's going on with me.